# How to use powerpoint automation services in SP2013

Tags: 2013, powerpoint-services

I don have office web apps installed. How do i test the powerpoint automation services in SP2013. Could any1 give me the detail steps to test the service.

Answer (score 1):

PowerPoint Automation Services is a server-side component that converts PowerPoint files (e.g. to PDF files). Same as Word Automation Services but for PowerPoint files.
This service targets developers who create code based on it, server-side, like in a WSP package.
This is a good choice when you want to convert documents in batch, on the server (where the use of the rich-client PowerPoint application is strictly forbidden, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757).
You can find details on scenarios and code usage in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/FP179894.aspx and http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2012/11/12/introduction-to-powerpoint-automation-services-in-sharepoint-server-2013.aspx.